# Sharepoint 2016 Infopath : The trial period for this product has expired

Tags: infopath2010, sharepoint-2016, trial

On opening InfoPath form in SharePoint 2016 , I am getting error

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
The trial period for this product has expired.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```
1.  Open IIS Management Console 
2.  Go to the Application Pool Page 
3.  look which users has been used for SharePoint 
4.  add this users to the local administration group 
5.  iisreset
```